# Arduino SD card need Write only to reduce memory

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I am using a Uno, GPS+SD card shield and LCD display and all runs fine with only 35% of memory used when **not** using the SD. When I add the SPI and SD Libraries for the SD card, combined they eat another 45% and I am getting a warning about reduced memory and the risk of unreliable performance. And, they are correct as sometimes writing to the SD doesn't work as expected.

The GPS/LCD work fine in their own Sketches. The SD/SPI work fine in their own Sketches. But when I combine the code I get the memory issues.

Since I only need to write to the SD card in CSV format, I am looking for a stripped down/SD/SPI combo that does only that as I can use a PC to read the data. I searched around and found a few possibles but they were all old and FAT16 only. I need to use FAT32 so I am currently stuck with SD/SPI.

I have ordered an Arduino Mega as it has 8M of memory so the problem should go away, but the original GPS is already set up in the dash of my truck and I would have to rebuild the brackets and project box for the Mega, so would like to just resolve the memory issue with the 4MB of the Uno. I am only going to use the Mega to make sure the full Sketch works OK and for 14-bucks, no big outlay for testing.

Can anyone help with a stripped down version of the SD/SPI combo as my code is tight enough until I add those Libraries.

Comment: Well, you should already have the source code of the SD and the SPI library, since they come bundled in the Arduino installation. You can strip it down by yourself, since I think that such a specific case is not common and so you won't be able to find it easily. Anyway unused functions usually are not compiled, so by removing them you will not get any space. I suggest you to look at the libraries and try to find buffers that you don't need and remove them...

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could get a stripped-down version of the GPS library.  [NeoGPS](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS) can be configured to be *very* small, both in terms of RAM and FLASH.  It's also the *fastest* library out there.  I wrote it because I had the same problem as you: combining multiple libraries in the smaller Arduinos revealed the bloat in all other GPS libraries: buffered copies of the sentences and data.